# How to rename an ansible role name?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have created an ansible role with name suppose role_A. Now i was asked to follow standard naming convention as per company standard. so is there any way i can rename my role name. Or simply mv command will work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply rename it using the command `mv role_A new_role_A`

Comment: I thought the same but never tested this. If that would have been possible then why would people use ansible-galaxy command to create a new role. I mean when we use ansible-galaxy command then it might be storing role name somewhere in config.

Comment: ansible-galaxy command is used to install roles from galaxy or GIT. When you create your own role you can just rename it.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to rename the ansible-role but i tackle it by creating another role and moved all files from old role to new role and deleted the old role.